# Target browser back and forward buttons individually

Tags: javascript

I am targeting both "back" and "forward" buttons together with this JavaScript snippet:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
   // do something cool
}
```

How can I distinguish between "back" and "forward" buttons and target their events separately?

Comment: One way I can think of is: when you `pushState` add a number to the state object, and increment it each time you `pushState`.  Now when you go forward or back you can compare that number to the current state, and check if that number is getting larger or smaller.  Not sure if this will work, but it's an idea.

Comment: You're welcome.  I don't know if there are "official" ways of doing this, but that sounds like it should work.  I'm a little busy, so I don't have time to whip up an example :-)

Comment: [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) might be worth looking into as well, although I believe it's more just for firing the events - not sure if you can hook onto the event too easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to track back/forward or history if you implement it correctly. Each XML file you load should be given a unique id, simply replace forward slashes with underscores and remember you shouldn't use underscores for actual urls, you use dashes instead. Presuming you don't have a url scheme that would make using Windows 8 seem non-homicidal by comparison you simply check for the id requested.

You can see how popstate works on my site...

http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/

Do a Ctrl+f and look at the code starting around the line...

```
window.onclick = function(e)
```

...here...

http://www.jabcreations.com/scripts/index.js

If you're using Firebug expand the #liquid (literally `<body><div id="body"><div id="content"><div id"liquid">` in my XHTML).

If you get lost let me know and I'll clarify what the code is doing. Also it helps tremendously to set your code to as strict as possible (XHTML as application/xhtml+xml and your XML content should be served as application/xml).

Comment: Serving content as `application/xhtml+xml` is a good way to break IE 8. Also, if your site ever goes down, this answer is useless. Please avoid linking and include code here instead.

Comment: Thanks for the vote-down @Stijn! Clearly you've never heard of content-negotiation. >__> You also CLEARLY visited my site using IE8 or older (NOT) to confirm this before mindlessly down-voting. Figaro asked a vague question, got an answer and accepted that, clearly their ability to move forward offends you.

Comment: Then you should be complete and mention the IE 8 issue. And I downvoted you for two reasons, not one. Actually I'll add a third. XHTML has been abandoned in favour of HTML 5.